# What is the best way to load balance javascript applications?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I write a lot of javascript applications and in many different circumstances the browser will become unresponsive or give a "slow script" error. Even when following best practices, initializing large data sets, complex animation, or when too many event handlers fire at once, I have to include extra setTimeouts or requestAnimationFrames around script blocks to load balance them. Seems like there should be some standard way of managing the browser load for large javascript applications.

Any ideas? It seems like there must be JS application designers thinking about this, but I can find nothing on the web or on stack.

***edit***

I appreciate all the response. My question is *not* "How can I write efficient Javascript?" which seems to be the question the current responses are answering. My question is: How can I balance the load of multiple sequential threads of javascripts running in the same browser?

I am well aware of all the information posted in the responses so far and appreciate the posters, but I am looking for a framework or a design pattern that balances script execution in a browser. This question is common in many other languages and for devops, I am simply asking the same question for javascript.

Comment: I think the term 'load balancing' has caused some confusion.  It doesn't apply, so the answerers have simply ignored that part.  But I think you have a specific question that can be addressed.

Answer (score 13):

You have a very short span of time in your hands.

Before talking about threads:

#### The DOM is slow

Really.

If your website is DOM-heavy, then find ways to offshore these manipulations. Use CSS3 transitions, use canvas for animations, avoid [unneccessary paints](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/unnecessary-paints/), etc.

There are also techniques to make it faster, like DocumentFragments, using off-DOM elements, etc.

#### JavaScript runs in a single thread in the browser

This means your scripts *have* to be *very* quick if you want the user to not feel any form of lag.

You can, for example, break intensive calculations into small fragments, for (a simple) example:

```
function findMax(arr){
   var currentMax = -Infinity;
   var i=0;
   setImmidiate(function() doWork{
       if(arr[i] > currentMax){
           currentMax = arr[i];
       }
       i++;
       if(i< arr.length){
           setImmidiate(doWork);
       }
   });
   return currentMax;
};
```

#### Wait, don't go yet! I lied! It's not really single threaded

JavaScript doesn't have to run single threaded in the browser any more! If you support modern browsers, you can [use WebWorkers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers). This will let you run intensive scripts in background threads and not interrupt the main program flow.

If you support modern browsers, this is probably the correct way to handle CPU intensive calculations.

WebWorkers let you use threads you're used to from other langauges but in a save (actor-system'ish) way. You can split work between workers and balance it just like you would in any other programming language.

Note web workers require IE10, Safari 4+, Opera 10.6 +, Chrome 3+ or Firefox 3.5+

#### One last thing

JavaScript is designed to perform asynchronous I/O, while this might not be what you're doing more often than not JavaScript performance issues might be the result of synchronous code where asynchronous code is appropriate. Synchronous event handling, blocking code, and more generally *anything that isn't CPU intensive* should take very little time any way and not require the use of 'the big guns' like web workers.

Comment: ...or you could load balance the scripts.

Comment: @BishopZ you keep using 'balance multiple threads in the browser'. Do you in fact mean balance multiple _actors_ in the browser? That is, are you using WebWorkers? Are you interested in balancing _those_ and when you say balance, what are your _bottlenecks_? Are you performing a lot of CPU? Do your Workers spend a lot of time waiting? This is a _very broad_ question in the general context, if you're willing to _specifiy_ what threading issue you're facing with your Workers I'll gladly help.

Comment: not currently using workers currently. The issue is that when too many events or animation trigger at the same time, they hang the browser. It is not inefficient code, but we are pushing the limits of the browser and need a way to manage multiple script that want to all run at the same time. does that help?

Comment: In that case that has little to do with threading or load balancing to begin with since you're not using threads to balance at all. One exception is CSS animations, those run on the GPU on a different thread and you can utilize them. If you're doing a lot of animating you'll eventually have to use Canvas and not DOM for animating and display. Workers only help you with CPU intensive stuff, you need to find out where you're blocking (the thread) first by profiling.

Comment: To compare here is something my coding-pal @copy made http://copy.sh/life/?pattern=glider&meta=1 It simulates game of life _in_ game of life working with millions of cells, it's single threaded and it runs decently fast here using `canvas`, are you really performing more raw calculations and animations than that? If you'd like more particular help you're welcome to come at the StackOverflow JavaScript room where we probably won't mind taking a look at your code, however, the more I read what you said the more I stand behind my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum there is one issue: @ copy's game uses canvas. The DOM is waaaaay slower. On jsperf, you can often see JS benchmarks running hundreds of thousands of operations per second. And you often see less than a thousand operations per second for DOM operations.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine you are absolutely correct :) which is why in the comment before that "If you're doing a lot of animating you'll eventually have to use Canvas and not DOM for animating and display"

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be writing synchronized JavaScript. JavaScript is single threaded in the browser. What you are doing is not load balancing - see [Load Balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29).

What best practices are you using? JavaScript is pretty quick in modern browsers, and if you're using even the most simple of best practices, unless you're doing something incredibly complex you should be fine.

Comment: I appreciate the response Jonathan. There is some confusion of language here. How better to describe than load balancing? It is not across multiple machines, but I do want to balance the load of multiple scripts running in a single environment.

Comment: Also, the whole purpose of requestAnimationFrame was that the browser can not handle too many function calls. This is how the browser environment is designed. These are best practices. Checkout this [Paul Irish article](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/).

Answer (score 3):

If a script is running slow (assuming client side code here), it generally isn't down to JS being slow. Your bottlenecks are far more likely to be found somewhere else. The notoriously slow DOM API, for example. 
As soon as you talk about DOM manipulations (such as animation), you're almost certainly going to notice a drop in speed.

A lot of people have (and are continuing to) critique the DOM API for being badly designed, overly complex at times, and down-right slow. 
The main issue with the DOM API is that it's not controlled by ECMA, as JavaScript is, but by W3. Simply put: client side JS is often 60-75% made up of DOM manipulations, but for those, JS relies on an API maintained and developed by a third party. I think it's pretty obvious that's just a recipe for slow-food.

Still, if you need to perform a lot of long and complex computations, a `Worker` allows you to (sort-of) spawn a background thread, which fires an event upon completion.

---

Another bottleneck that *can* be noticeable is the over-usage of libs/toolkits such as jQuery. These often aren't very modular in terms of allowing you to include only those bits you really need, and bring with them an additional overhead. Compare

```
document.getElementById('foo');//calls DOM API
```

to

```
$('#foo');//calls jQuery init, a few if's and else's to make up what to do
          //then string is passed to querySelector (DOM API), 
          //new jQ object is constructed (which also constructs an array)
          //return new jQObject
```

At least, that's what sort of happened behind the scenes in jQuery. 
While I'm on the subject of jQ: a lot of jQ code actually binds too many event listeners, bringing us to a third (and, for now, last) possible bottleneck.

---

Event listeners are checked in an infinite loop, as you probably well know. If you have 1 listener, you won't notice any loss in performance. If you bind a 1000 individual handlers directly to references to individual Nodes, you will. Each reference is kept in memory, all the handlers (fuction objects) are, too. 
Event delegation isn't that hard and it can make the event loop a lot faster, [as I have found out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331203/javascript-how-to-simulate-change-event-in-internet-explorer-delegation)

Comment: While I agree the DOM API is very problematic (and badly designed, and overly complex) . The DOM API is actually _pretty fast_ in modern browsers. For example, my browser can make over 20 million DOMelement selections per second, more than 16 million tag name selections, here is a jsperf I put up for this http://jsperf.com/is-the-dom-really-slow. Related lecture: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs . I agree that performance problems sometimes stem from abuse of selectors, but I wouldn't call the DOM slow

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I will check the lecture, but a jspref alone isn't going to convince me, I must say. If you write animations in JS, and need to move 2 nodes, that means: getting node, setting it's properties to move 5 pixels in some direction, sending that data back to the DOM (which has to be re-rendered) and start again. On a single thread, with the DOM being out of your control, I think your JS thread might find itself waiting a lot (Data sent: waiting for DOM to say it's ready again)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the edit. I think it improves the answer substantially. However, I still think the DOM is pretty fast, much too fast to be a performance issue in most cases. Here is a case where I'm _horribly abusing_ the DOM to animate 100 divs with borders at once http://jsfiddle.net/gJ5Ak/ it's still smooth here even when I add transparency and colors http://jsfiddle.net/3Q4kn/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yes, you're heavy on the DOM, but you're also using `requestAnimationFrame`, which the OP mentions as something he has to use in order for his code to run smoothly. `requestAnimationFrame` hasn't been around for long, and isn't part of the DOM API, either... it's a notifier-function to schedule a repaint

Comment: Event listeners aren't checked in an infinite loop.  That would be horrid - they're fired off when an event happens.  Binding 1000 individual handlers is slow because it has to hold the instances in memory and fire off the appropriate ones when the event fires.  It's not continually checking all of them.

Comment: @Izkata: [MDN's view on the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop) does come very close to an infinite loop, if you ask me: `while(q.waitFormMsg()){ q.processNextMsg();}`... as long as a page is active, the event loop is running, that is, so I've been told, how it works. event's aren't interrupts, are they?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Ah, "infinite loop" often implies a busy loop - something more like `while (true) { q.processNextMsg(); }`.  _That's_ what I thought you were talking about.  Internally, I would guess there probably is an interrupt, and `q.waitFormMsg()` will only return after it was triggered.  Next best would be that it includes a sleep, but that would delay event firing.

Comment: @Izkata: yes, I'm entirely with you: internally, an event firing probably is an interrupt. But (being most active on SO), I usually don't use the word _"interrupt"_ when answering JS questions, to avoid confusion

Answer (score 3):

Aside from any specific techniques, modern browser dev tools all have JavaScript profilers. Switch them on and run through some tasks and see which functions are taking the most time. Attack each bottleneck one at a time.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but debugging is not load balancing either. This is a common question is lots of other languages and platforms. Why does javascript have no answer?

Comment: Profiling is not debugging. It's step 1 when you're optimizing. Load balancing usually implies splitting load across machines which is obviously not an option in client-side code. And JavaScript is single-threaded by design  like any other UI platform. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544447/why-are-most-ui-frameworks-single-threaded

Comment: In general, I've seen very few websites running Javascript that actually do some form of processing that takes time. Usually, any of that will happen on the server through an AJAX call. That's why jiggy and I are pretty dubious about the idea of "load balancing" unless your site lets the user calculate Pi.

Answer (score 1):

As many others have said already, you can't really "load balance" javascript. Unless you're using workers, javascript does one thing at a time. The best you can hope to do is work on getting tasks out of the queue faster than they're coming in. Here's some things to look at:

### Be careful with the DOM

A big part of that is, as the other answers state, avoiding DOM redraws, as they can be extremely expensive. Try to do all your DOM reads in one step, and all your writes in another, as reading from the DOM often causes it to draw all the queued changes to make sure it has up to date information. If you're using the information to make more DOM changes, then it'll redraw again, and the user will never even see that first redraw.

### Avoid `setInterval`

If the callback function takes longer than the interval to run, you'll get multiple copies of the callback function in the queue, and you code will just fall farther and farther behind as it runs. This is why many people suggest using a `setTimeout` that sets itself when it's done. That way, there's only ever one instance of the callback waiting in the queue.

### Buffer "Burst" Events

Some events fire several times at once, but really you should only be reacting the last last occurrence. One example of this I've seen often is a scroll event listener. When the user's scrolling the page, this event can fire multiple times a second, and if the listener does any real work, then you're queue's building up way faster than it's clearing. That's why you often see patterns like this:

```
var scrollTimer;

function scrollHandler(e) {
    // Actually handle the scrolling, DOM manipulations, real work...
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(scrollHandler, 100, e);
});
```

This way, no matter how much the user scrolls, the heavy code doesn't actually run until they stop scrolling (in this case for a tenth of a second).

### Cache Continuous Events

I've found that in some situations certain events come in almost continuously, and have multiple listeners. If you're reacting to the accelerometer, GPS, Game controllers (or keyboards being used as controllers), then the events will probably be coming in as fast as they possibly can, triggering their listeners almost constantly. [Everythings trying to happen as fast as possible, and that makes it slow](http://gossmati.ca/blog/aukera3-update-loop/). Unlike the "burst" events, however, you can't just wait for these events to stop before reacting. The whole point is to react as they change.

If you think about it though, your code only needs to react once per frame. Have a single keydown/keyup listener that sets flags for the keys you want. Have a single accelerometer listener update and array with orientation data, or a GPS listener store the latitude and longitude. These listeners should be fast enough to keep the queue emptying as quickly as it fills. With that in place, you can loop through all your objects once a frame and just have them check the flags and arrays for the information they need.

Answer (score 1):

So based on your edits I read this as asking "how do I effectively divide up a long running calculation into multiple web workers." I've been writing [a library for dealing with web workers](http://communistjs.com/) and here's what I found, there are a couple different ways you can do this which often depend on the data.  Assuming you have a array that you want to process using n workers.

1. You can just arbitrarily split up the array in n parts and send a part to each worker. Either through slicing the array (if it's small) or by iterating through the list and sending each chunk of data to a different worker (via Math.random() or %).  If your data items take a fairly uniform amount of time to process this is going to be as fast as a queue but isn't going to have the overhead.
2. You can set up a queue so that after processing a piece of data the worker sends the result back and gets the next piece. This will balance the load pretty well and means that if one piece of data takes 500ms and the rest takes 1ms you won't have of data waiting behind the 500ms piece.  But you now have workers waiting to get their data and other added complexity that can lead to slower times then the first queue types, but also faster in others, especially if you use transferable objects to speed up transfer times.
3. You can just do it one worker.  This isn't actually a solution to the question you asked, but could be a solution to the problem you have, I find it's really a good idea to double check that the overhead of dividing your data up into multiple parts doesn't outweigh the benefits you get. Especially considering that since Chrome doesn't support workers making more workers you have to do the dividing up in the DOM thread.

Answer (score 1):

The term load balancing is confusing here and I think that has led to some answers that you don't feel are helpful.

First off, all of the advice given in the other answers is sound.  Please listen to the other experts here.

Now on to your load balancing.  Load balancing means to create multiple workers and distribute work to them transparently.  Traditionally, it means having multiple servers serve client requests.  But I see how it applies to your JavaScript performance issue here.

It sounds like you are trying to see if you can break your code up into multiple processes or threads so that they can run in parallel.  Two problems with that:

1. Parallelizing something doesn't speed it up as dramatically as you might think and adds complexity / risk and sometimes even performance penalties as you add synchronization points around your [critical sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section).
2. JavaScript is single-threaded.  Even if you want to take the risk of creating multiple threads, you cannot.

That said, there is a possible solution.  There is a new technology called web workers designed for message passing and handling.  That can probably give you what you need.  However, I don't believe (could be mistaken here) that it is supported by all browsers.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Mozilla's developer site has good information about thread safety issues.  Read that over before you pursue this course.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: Thank you for the first answer that is not "How to optimize your code." I use web workers regularly, but am looking for a framework for balancing execution across web workers. I know I could write this framework myself, but it seems so strange that something like this does not exist. Thank you again for your response.

Answer (score 0):

So there are some long-winded answers here that are actually likely all correct. However, for your particular site, I'd consider it pretty likely that there are 1 to 5 functions that steal 99% of the CPU time, and could be 80%-optimized with some work.

Most browsers have code-profiling tools that will allow you to watch the code as you do something slow, and then tell you what the browser spent the most time doing. Whatever's at the top of the list afterwards is what you should focus on first.

The stuff about web workers, for instance, is really neat. But, in a basic webpage only using Javascript for a better user experience (as opposed to doing some sort of actual work) I'd be surprised if that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

To address the "load balancing" aspect of your question, I'd say that it is impossible for browser-based JavaScript.

"Load balancing" implies that you have more than one machine to work against. I.e. if deploying a RESTful service, you'd have many machines running the same service and spread out the traffic amongst them. This idea really doesn't apply to JavaScript running in browsers (node.js is a different story) because you've only got one client machine. There isn't a way to spread the load out to other machines.

"Threading" is probably a better analogy (as others have mentioned). In general, threading isn't really available in JavaScript, but you can use HTML5 Web Workers to achieve a similar result... but then you're restricted to supported browsers.